# Include a MJPEG in a html-Site, using video.js

Tags: javascript, html, video.js, mjpeg

Here's my case:
I get a Stream from a Web-Server. The format of this Stream is MJPEG. I embedded this stream in a html-site with the following code: `<img src="http://172.17.52.161:9000/stream/video.mjpeg">`, but I'd like to use a Player for this stream. Is there a possibility to use video.js with mjpeg-streams?
My overall goal is to compile these files with Phonegap-Build, to use it on my Smartphone, is this possible?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I can't find much but there is an answer here, it doesn't solve your issue per say but it gives a direction to look for an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346775/rendering-mjpeg-stream-in-html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `<video>` tag

```
<video src="http://172.17.52.161:9000/stream/video.mjpeg" controls>
   Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

Comment: i couldn't get either img or video tag to work. is there any settings I need to configure on IIS? MIME type etc?

Comment: @maryhadalittlelamb   post a proper well describe  question .. .. with your code ..  ...the info  you provided in this comment is not enough ..

Comment: video tag method (gives a player with "Invalid source error")
    <video src="http://127.0.0.1/somevideo.mjpeg" controls>
    </video> 

img tag method (gives a small box of cross x)
    <img src="http://127.0.0.1/somevideo.mjpeg"/>

Comment: @maryhadalittlelamb    . post a porper  question . ..please .. i can't understand  this way ..

Comment: as i cant place pictures and such in comments. i posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361873/stream-mjpeg-video-view-able-on-both-chrome-and-ie11

Comment: @scaisEdge Do not confuse Mpeg and Mjpeg