# Stream .mjpeg video view-able on both Chrome and IE11

Tags: c#, html, streaming, mjpeg

I hosted a .mjpeg file locally http://127.0.0.1/web/Images/Stream/somevideo.mjpeg

I tried a few codes in my cshtml page.

**1. Video tag method**

```
    <video src="http://127.0.0.1/web/Images/Stream/somevideo.mjpeg" controls></video>
```

[image: Shown in IE]

**2. img tag method**

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/web/Images/Stream/somevideo.mjpeg"/>
```

[image: Shown in IE]

**3. motionjpeg javascript method**

The code below copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346775/rendering-mjpeg-stream-in-html5/19370054#19370054)

```
<img id="motionjpeg" src="http://127.0.0.1/web/Images/Stream/somevideo.mjpeg" />
<script>
        //Using jQuery for simplicity
        function motionjpeg(id) {
            var image = $(id), src;

            if (!image.length) return;

            src = image.attr("src");
            if (src.indexOf("?") < 0) {
                image.attr("src", src + "?"); // must have querystring
            }

            image.on("load", function() {
                // this cause the load event to be called "recursively"
                this.src = this.src.replace(/?[^\n]*$/, "?") +
                    (new Date()).getTime(); // 'this' refers to the image
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            motionjpeg("#motionjpeg"); // Use the function on the image
        });
</script>
```

**4. clipchamp javascript method**

The only [code](https://clipchamp.com/blog/2015/how-to-play-back-mjpeg-animated-gif-and-mp4-video-on-web-sites/) that works, however only on Chrome but not IE

```
<div id="mjpeg_player" style="width:600px;"></div>
<script src='http://127.0.0.1/web/Scripts/jquery-clipchamp-mjpeg-player-plugin-master/src/jquery.clipchamp.mjpeg.player.js'></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var mjpegUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/web/Images/Stream/somevideo.mjpeg";
            var fps = 20;
            var autoloop = true;

            $('#mjpeg_player').clipchamp_mjpeg_player(mjpegUrl, fps, autoloop,
                function(wrapperElement, playerInterface) {
                    /*
                    $('#mjpeg_player_stop').click(function(){
                        playerInterface.finish();
                    });
                    */
                });
        });
</script>
```

FYI, I configured the MIME type of .mpjeg as application/octet-stream

Comment: hi, did you sort the issue finally? I'm standing in front of the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `multipart/x-mixed-replace` ?
You will also have to provide boundary parameter so it will look something like this: `multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--boundary` you will have to figure out which boundary is used on your hosted mjpeg file to delimit separate frame contents.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the correct mime-type for M-JPEG i.e. Motion JPEG  is

```
video/x-motion-jpeg
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried 
application/octet-stream
video/x-motion-jpeg
video/mpeg
video/mp4
None of them worked.