# How can I export CSS animation as animated PNG, gif, or WEBP *with transparency*?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, animated-gif

Press **"Run code snippet"** below to see the animated loading spinner that I want to save.

I want to replace all green colors with transparency.

Also, I'd like the animation to loop perfectly.

I tried recording a screen capture video using OBS and then uploading to https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif and using the "Replace color with transparency" feature, but it didn't remove any green color at all.

Also, if exporting [`canvas` animations](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/NpoxEe/) is easier than capturing CSS animations, I'd accept an answer that shows me how.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vf;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #090;
}
.container {
  background-color: #0c0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
.sym {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(white 50%, black 0);
  animation: r 8s linear infinite;
}
.sym:before, .sym:after {
  --i: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: calc((1 - var(--i))*50%);
  bottom: 25%;
  left: calc(var(--i)*50%);
  border: solid 16.6666666667px hsl(0, 0%, calc(var(--i)*100%));
  transform-origin: calc(var(--i)*100%) 50%;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  background: hsl(0, 0%, calc((1 - var(--i))*100%));
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: s 4s ease-in-out calc(var(--i)*-4s) infinite alternate;
  content: '';
}
.sym:after {
  --i: 1;
}
@keyframes s {
  to {
transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
@keyframes r {
  to {
transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
/* from https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/aJPMre/ */
```

```html
<body>
<div class='container'>
 <div class='sym'></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Almost 5 years later and I still love this animation. 

Answer (score 4):

I used [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) to capture a video of my browser as mp4.

Then I used ffmpeg [like this](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/28042/5657) to replace the green chroma key color with transparency and save as an animated gif file:

```
ffmpeg -t 9 -i screenCapture.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]colorkey=0x2dd103:0.3:0.5,format=yuva420p,crop=500:500:6:427,split[v0][v1];[v0]palettegen[p];[v1][p]paletteuse,setpts=0.1*PTS" -r 100 final.gif
```

Note that I think `-t 9` and `setpts=0.1*PTS` and `-r 100` *should* combine in a way that affects whether an animation is captured precisely from start to end, but I haven't mastered it.

So the remaining problems are to make sure that the gif loops seamlessly (which I think will be possible by removing superfluous frames via [RealWorld Paint](http://www.rw-designer.com/image-editor)) and to make sure that the animation speed is appropriate in PowerPoint 2013.

(I'd still prefer to accept a cleaner, more convenient answer, as this approach is time-consuming and error-prone.)