# Capturing canvas to video in fastes way

Tags: canvas, ffmpeg, seek

I'm capturing canvas which contains things like videos, images and text, but I capture each frame per frame, using the `onseeked` event to capture the next frame after seeking the video to the desired frame.
But it's taking a long time.

Is there a way to capture canvas faster? e.g. Using GPU acceleration or dedicated software.

EDIT :

```
function download() {
      const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.style.display = 'none';
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'test.webm';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }, 100);
    }

    function handleDataAvailable(event) {
      if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
      }
    }

    function handleStop(event) {
      console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
      const superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
      document.querySelector('video').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
    }

    function stopRecording() {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', recordedBlobs);
      document.querySelector('video').controls = true;
    }


    function startRecording() {
      videos.forEach(element =>{
        element.play();
      });
      var stream = document.querySelector('canvas').captureStream(30);

      let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
      recordedBlobs = [];
      try {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
      } catch (e0) {
        console.log('Unable to create MediaRecorder with options Object: ', e0);
        try {
          options = {mimeType: 'video/webm,codecs=vp9'};
          mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
        } catch (e1) {
          console.log('Unable to create MediaRecorder with options Object: ', e1);
          try {
            options = 'video/vp8'; // Chrome 47
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
          } catch (e2) {
            alert('MediaRecorder is not supported by this browser.\n\n' +
              'Try Firefox 29 or later, or Chrome 47 or later, ' +
              'with Enable experimental Web Platform features enabled from chrome://flags.');
            console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e2);
            return;
          }
        }
      }

      mediaRecorder.onstop = handleStop;
      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
      mediaRecorder.start(100); // collect 100ms of data
      console.log('MediaRecorder started', mediaRecorder);
      const startTime = getTime();
      let nextExpTime = startTime;
      var curTime = null;

      const onTimer = () => {
        videos.forEach(element =>{
          let dureeTotale = element.duration; // Durée de la vidéo en cours
          if(frameNum == 1){
            element.play();
            element.pause();
          }
          // let seek = ((frameNum % (dureeTotale * 30 +1)) / 30); // Si dépassement, retour à 0 secondes;
          let framerate = numFrames / dureeTotale;
          if ((element.currentTime * framerate) === numFrames){
            stopRecording();
            download();
            // capturer.stop();
            // capturer.save(showVideoLink);
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
          }
        })

      };

      onTimer();
      const timer = setInterval(onTimer, 0);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Need to show your ffmpeg command and the complete log.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save canvas animation as gif or webm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681683/how-to-save-canvas-animation-as-gif-or-webm)

Comment: I assume you are in an html page with javascript. If not, can you please add the tags relevant to your environment in your question please?

Comment: Yes it's an html page with javascript, the HTML page contains a canvas which contains elements like videos or pictures. About the link you posted, I try a similar, look the code I just added :) Thanks for your help

Comment: @Kaiido do you have any idea ? :)

Comment: Nobody have an idea ?