# How to show an extermal livestream on a webpage

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, streaming

I have been asked to add a live stream video to an existing website. The stream URL is, say, http://192.168.1.2/, and I can view it in VLC. The container is MPEG-TS, and the codec shown by VLC is `Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264)`, and from what I [read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video), this should be supported by all major browsers.

My current HTML code is simply this:

```html
<video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay controls>
    <source src="http://192.168.1.2/" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But this does not show anything. In both Chrome and Edge, I can see the video player with a spinning circle, and the F12 Network tab shows that some data is being downloaded from the stream (roughly 1 MB in 24 seconds, then it stops).

Firefox almost immediately shows a message *No video with supported format and MIME type found*, and downloads nothing. There is a warning in the console: *HTTP “Content-Type” of “application/octet-stream” is not supported. Load of media resource http://192.168.1.2/ failed.* The stream response does have that content-type header, but I'm not sure if that would prevent playing it. I assume that Firefox is more picky than Edge and Chrome.

My question is: Is it actually possible to show streaming video in a `video` element? And if not, is there an  alternative? I tried to use `fetch` and assign the result to `video.src`, but the first step already fails because of CORS restrictions. However, if this is a feasible approach, I could ask the owner of the stream to add support for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can show streaming video in a video element, provided you're using a separate javascript library to demux the incoming stream (Some examples are [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) and [flv.js](http://bilibili.github.io/flv.js/) ). Really only iOS devices support live streaming in a native `<video>` element by itself (HLS video).

You can sort out what kind of stream is incoming by using [`ffprobe`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) or maybe by looking at the `Content-Type` of the http request you're making. `application/octet-stream` is a generic content type, so I wouldn't be certain you're actually grabbing the real content in that request.

Lastly, you'll likely be dealing with CORS/mixed-content issues for anything live streaming *(unless you're loading a [mjpeg stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346775/rendering-mjpeg-stream-in-html5?rq=1)...which you aren't if you've got H.264 video)*. You'll need to get that sorted out.

Comment: Thanks, very informative. It turned out that the container used is MPEG-TS, which apparently is not (widely) supported by browsers natively, but it looks like hls.js would take care of that too.